# Get database data in xml format using wcf service

Tags: c#, mysql, wcf

Please check my code below

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    System.Xml.XmlDocumentGetData(int userId);
}

public MySqlConnectionStringBuilder Sbu = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    public static DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    public static DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();

    public XmlDocument GetData(int  userId)
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection()
         String Query = "select * from user_master  where UserID =  "+userId;
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter =new MySqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand =new MySqlCommand(Query,con);
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        myDataSet.Tables.Add(dt);
       string xmlStr = "";
       XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
       xmlStr = myDataSet.GetXml();
       xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlStr);

      return xmlDoc;
}
```

Exception occurred:

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to localhost. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

Consuming through client

```
ServiceProxy.Service1Client client = new ServiceProxy.Service1Client();

client.GetData(Convert.ToInt32(txtUserID.Text));
```

Comment: Why do you return an XmlDocument and not just a string that contains XML? Frankly I don't think that will ever work.

Comment: ok thank could please give me example or suggestion what to do here?

Comment: Just change your function result type to `string` and return `xmlStr` as your function result instead of loading it into an `XmlDocument`.

Comment: one mpre exception "DataTable already belongs to this DataSet."  here myDataSet.Tables.Add(dt);

Comment: Then create the `DataSet` in your method instead of as a global field.